# Downclocking of 1600 ram to support on 1066 motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

I bought a ddr3 1600 mhz ram, but my motherboard is 1066mhz , can i downclock the ram to make it compatible for my motherboard
my bios is american megatrends .inc

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q4UxOeY.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0c2e.jpg]

Comment: This downclocking should happen automatically.

Comment: but it did not happened

Comment: Since your system is not booting at all because your MB [doesn't support](http://superuser.com/questions/924221/new-4-gb-ram-no-boot-and-no-signal#comment1250172_924221) the RAM, I would recommend changing one of the two components. RAM is easier to change naturally, but it's up to you. Edit: You can try updating the BIOS if there's a new one available from Intel, but if that doesn't help there's precious little you can do except change one of the two.

Comment: Is it not booting, or why do you worry about it?

Comment: it is not booting, now i am using my old ram

Comment: how can find my bios update